# Scaling all children of sprite

Tags: flash

I have a container which has many child MCs. I am wanting to scale and center a point in the container without the actual container resizing.

It seems that any sort of scaling i do affects the size of the container itself.

```
    obj.scaleX=1.1;
    obj.scaleY=1.1;
```

If it possible to scale the contents of a sprite without it changing the size of the parent container?

I want to be able to pan around the container once it has zoomed to be able to see all of the contents.

Is this possible to do, or do i need to add something additional to get this effect.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is, apply a mask to the parent, then scale the parent. This will scale it properly without it expanding the space the MC takes up.